# Unidentifiable NZEC Error in Code-ENTEXAM

Tags: java, arrays, exception, runtime

I was working on one of the problems on codechef.com https://www.codechef.com/problems/ENTEXAM

Here is my solution for the problem-

```
import java.io.*;
class Entrance_Final
{
static BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   static int test_case=0;//Test cases
   static int students=0;
   static int qualifiers=0;
   static long result=0;
   static int exams=0;
   static long max_marks=0;
   static long[]sigma_res;
   static long sergey_score=0;
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        //System.out.println("Enter number of test cases.");
        test_case=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for(int lv=1;lv<=test_case;lv++)
            comp_min_marks();   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public static void comp_min_marks()throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        //System.out.println("Enter students,enrollees,exams and maximum marks.");
        String a=in.readLine();
        a=a.trim();
        int flag=0;
        int times=1;
        for(int lv=0;lv<a.length();lv++)
        {
            if(a.charAt(lv)==' '&&(times==1))
            {
                students=Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0,lv));
                flag=lv+1;
                times++;
            }
            else if(a.charAt(lv)==' '&&(times==2))
            {
                qualifiers=Integer.parseInt(a.substring(flag,lv));
                flag=lv+1;
                times++;
            }
            else if(a.charAt(lv)==' '&&(times==3))
            {
                exams=Integer.parseInt(a.substring(flag,lv));
                flag=lv+1;
                times++;
                max_marks=Long.parseLong(a.substring(flag));
                break;
            }
        }
        sigma_res=new long[students-1];
        //System.out.println("Enter the marks of all the students during their exams,each ones in one line");
        for(int lv=0;lv<students-1;lv++)
        {
            String b=in.readLine();
            sigma_res[lv]=int_sum(b);
        }
        //System.out.println("Now enter Sergey's scores");
        if(exams==1)
        {
            //String b=in.readLine();
            sergey_score=0;
        }
        else
        {
            String b=in.readLine();
            sergey_score=int_sum(b);
        }
        sigma_res=doQuickSort(0,students-2);
        result=sigma_res[students-qualifiers-1]-sergey_score+1;
        if(result<0)
            System.out.println("0");
        else if(result<=max_marks)
            System.out.println(result);
        else
            System.out.println("Impossible");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public static long int_sum(String b)throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        b=b.trim();
        long res=0;
        int flag=0;
        for(int lv=0;lv<b.length();lv++)
        {
            if(b.charAt(lv)==' ')
            {
                res+=Long.parseLong(b.substring(flag,lv));
                flag=lv+1;
            }
        }
        res+=Long.parseLong(b.substring(flag));
        return res;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
        return -1;
    }
}

private static long[] doQuickSort(int low,int high)throws IOException
{
    try
    {

        if(high-low<1)
            return sigma_res;

        int wall=low;
        int pivot_pos=(int)(Math.random()*(high-low))+low;
        long pivot=sigma_res[pivot_pos];
        long temp=sigma_res[high];
        sigma_res[high]=pivot;
        sigma_res[pivot_pos]=temp;
        pivot_pos=high;
        for(int lv=low;lv<=high-1;lv++)
        {
            if(pivot>sigma_res[lv])
            {
                temp=sigma_res[lv];
                sigma_res[lv]=sigma_res[wall];
                sigma_res[wall]=temp;
                wall++;
            }
        }
        temp=sigma_res[wall];
        sigma_res[wall]=pivot;
        sigma_res[pivot_pos]=temp;
        pivot_pos=wall;    
        doQuickSort(low,wall-1);
        doQuickSort(wall+1,high);
        return sigma_res;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
        return sigma_res;
    }
}
```

}

As you have probably noticed, I have enclosed all the code within my program in rather redundant try-catch blocks returning arbitrary exceptions. This is because I am always getting an NZEC-Error for my code (when I submit it online) and despite using these blocks, the error is persisting. I have repeatedly had a look at the constraints of the problem but had no luck figuring out what the issue is.

P.S I do not have access to the test cases of this problem.

Comment: Post the stack trace for the errors

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no response here and I was able to figure out the issue, I suppose I might as well as answer my question. So first of all there was no exception at all, instead I was getting a VirtualMachineError in the line

```
sigma_res=new long[students-1];
```

(No idea why this was happening,all I know is the value of 'students' exceeded its constraint-defined limits).

After looking at a few solutions, I figured the issue was caused by taking the println statements out of the main() method and placing them in another one.

The moment I put the println statement back into main(), the solution was accepted.

P.S I still don't know why the program wouldn't terminate when the println statements where in another method.